# If L* is regular, then is L regular?

Tags: regular-language

I've tried to look for the answer and I'm getting conflicting answers so I'm not sure. I know the reverse is true, that if L is regular then L* is regular under closure.

I imagine that if L* is regular then L is regular because the subset of L* should be regular and L is part of that subset.

Comment: A subset of a regular language is not necessarily regular: `0^n1^n` is a subset of `0*1*`, after all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was having trouble thinking of an example.

Comment: This is a little off-topic; you'll probably get a better response at cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 6):

If L* is regular, then L is not necessarily regular. For example, consider any nonregular language L over an alphabet Σ such that Σ ⊆ L. (That is, imagine you have a nonregular language where each individual character in the alphabet is a string in L.) In that case, L* = Σ*, since you can form any string as the concatenation of all the individual characters of Σ.

Here's one possible example. Let Σ = {a} and consider the language L = { a<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup> | n ∈ N }. This language is not regular, and you can prove it using either the pumping lemma for regular languages or the Myhill-Nerode theorem. However, the language L* is the language a*, which is regular. To see this, notice that since L contains the string a, the language L* contains all strings of the form a<sup>n</sup> for any natural number n.

Another option: pick L to be any nonregular language over Σ, then consider the language L ∪ Σ. This is also a nonregular language (if L ∪ Σ were regular, then we could subtract out each character added in via the union, leaving a regular language at each step, to show that L is regular), and it satisfies the above requirements.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did you mean Whole Numbers and not Natural Numbers? (for the language L)

Comment: @Tinkidinki I did intend to use natural numbers there. I haven’t seen the term whole numbers used in formal mathematics before, though I definitely remember learning about them in primary school.

Answer (score 3):

Take L = {a,b}*, which is regular, but has a non-regular subset L={a^n b^n} (this one can be proved to be non regular by pumping lemma...), so it's not the case that all subsets of a regular language are regular.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that answers your questions after two years :D

Comment: Yeah my bad a^n b^n

Comment: My apologies - I see what you were going for here. If you edit your answer to address the fact that you're pointing out that the claim "If L is regular, then every subset of L is regular" is false, I'll replace the downvote with an upvote.

Comment: You can read in parenthesis that I am saying this one can be proved to be non regular meaning if L* is regular it doesnt mean L its subset has to be also regular that's the point...

Comment: But in this case your language L = {a^n b^n | n in N } doesn't have have the property that L* = {a, b}*, since L* doesn't contain aab, for example.

Comment: bro if a and b are both raised to the power of n that means their are equal number of a's and b's

Comment: Yes, exactly. So perhaps I misinterpreted your answer? Weren't you claiming that {a^n b^n | n in N}* = {a,b}*?

Comment: I can't remove my downvote until you edit your answer (the site won't let me). Can you rewrite your answer to more clearly articulate your point? If so, I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: forget it I forgot half of what I learned I didn't even like this course lol but yeah that answer is 100 percent correct i am sure